# can we separate only account module from the OpenERP 7.0?

Tags: odoo

i am new in OpenERP,can anyone please tell me how to extract only accounting module from the OpenERP 7.0?is it possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to extract only accounting module and use it, as openerp is a suite of integrated modules. You can choose only to use Accounting if you don't want to use other modules like Stock and MRP.